# Is there any #define equivalent in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am implementing some basic state machine which several states in Julia.

In C I would trace the current state using something similar to:

```
#define STOP 1
#define START 2
#define ERROR 3
```

And then use the friendly constants in comparisons, etc.

```
if(state == STOP) {
    printf("Stop state.\n");
}
```

Is there something equivalent to #define in Julia?

Comment: Sounds like you want an enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [enum](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Enums.@enum). Enums are defined using the `@enum` macro:

```
@enum State STOP START ERROR
```

This creates three constants, `STOP`, `START`, and `ERROR`, all of type `State`. This means you can dispatch functions on the type of an enum:

```
import Base.println
function println(s::State)
    if s == STOP
        println("Stop state.")
    elseif s == START
        println("Start state.")
    else
        println("Error state.")
    end
end
```

```
julia> s = STOP

julia> println(s)
Stop state.
```

Enums can be converted to integer values:

```
julia> Int.([STOP, START, ERROR])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 1
 2
```

As you can see, the default integer values for the sequence of enum states starts at `0`. However, you can choose to explicitly set the integer values for the enums when you use the `@enum` macro:

```
julia> @enum Heat LOW=1 MEDIUM=2 HIGH=3

julia> Int.([LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Note that when creating a switch, like in the `println` definition above, you can be confident that `STOP`, `START`, and `ERROR` are the only possible values of a `State` object. This can be demonstrated by explicitly constructing `State` objects:

```
julia> State(0), State(1), State(2)
(STOP::State = 0, START::State = 1, ERROR::State = 2)

julia> State(3)
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid value for Enum State: 3
Stacktrace:
 [1] enum_argument_error(::Symbol, ::Int64) at ./Enums.jl:34
 [2] State(::Int64) at ./Enums.jl:139
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really want something as close a possible to `#define <Symbol> <Integer>` use `const`:

```
const STOP  = 1
const START = 2
const ERROR = 3
```

Comment: Thanks this is also relevant, I guess for the specific `state` variable makes more sense to use the enum though (even when the question does not explicitly asks for it).